# Continuous linear operations

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces. Suppose that $\dim X<\infty$. Then every linear operator $T\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Can anyone help me with the proof please or where to start?

Answer (score 1):

You might start by letting $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be a normalized basis for $X$ (with $\dim(X) = N$) and setting $k = \max_i \{\|T e_i\| \}$; then showing that there is some $C > 0$ such that $\|T v\| \leq C\, k$ for every $v$ with $\|v \| = 1$. (An easy choice is $C = N$).

Another approach is to let $\{ x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $X$ converging to some $x \in X$, and showing that $T x_n \to Tx$, considering each component of the sequence in some fixed basis.